# How to Rank Student Marks in Codeigniter Function

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, functional-programming, ranking

Can someone please help me to get the student rank function in codeigniter. How can I rank their subject mark of each subject of each student on their report. 
this is an example below. I want to get something like this;

```
Name: Ben Wade
|Subject  |Test Score| Rank | Grade |  Remarks |
| English |    87    |  2   |   A+  | Excellent|
| Maths   |    76    |  3   |   B+  | V. Good|

Name: John Doe
|Subject  |Test Score| Rank | Grade |  Remarks |
| English |    97    |  1   |   A+  | Excellent|
| Maths   |    81    |  1   |   A+  | Excellent|
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough to get an answer; You'll have to provide the table structure & a clear explanation on what you're trying to do & where you're stuck.

Comment: I have reformatted my question, please help.

Comment: create the field in your table; query all students for each subject & update the field with their rank to make it sticky ... Although you can get the rank with a single query & without creating the field, but it would be slower than this approach since your students would be calling their report more than once.

Answer (score 1):

```
$highest_marks = $this->db->get('mark')->result_array();
rsort($highest_marks);
foreach($highest_marks as $row) {
        echo $row['mark_obtained'];
}
```

Retrive the `resut_array()` and then `rsort()` which would sort it in descending order. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: no Eisa. I want to get their rank of marks in subject of each student subject mark as revised above. Please help.

Comment: Remove this `$this->db->select_max('mark_obtained');` and then try my code